# Error al enlazar css y js en el html "('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type"

Tags: html, mime

recientemente mude mi sitio a otro hosting con cPanel y me aaprecio este error que nunca antes me había aparecido.

Me canse de leer pero no pude encontrar nada, les comento que hice de todo, mas abajo les voy a dejar los pasos que hice para intentar solucionarlo.

1: agregue `<base href = "/" />`

2: Los tag para enlazar las hojas de estilo tienen este formato `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/styles/custom-style.css"/>`

No se si servirá pero les dejo mi HTACCESS
https://pastebin.com/pKc4xr01

Este es el error que me aparece en la consola de Chrome y no termina de enlazar las hojas de estilo, el servidor esta en PHP

```
Refused to apply style from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Comment: ¿Ha comprobado qué se devuelve desde esa URL? Si hay un error, igual te está devolviendo una página de error 404 que es lo que es "text/html".

Comment: Eso hace exactamente, estoy utilizando AltoRouter y todas las direcciones van al index.php pero cuando encuentra un archivo como css,img, js etc, entonces te muestra ese archivo y no te redirecciona.
Funciona bien en otro host  o en un servidor local